# update next row based on previous ID

Tags: mysql

let say i have a table named `banners`. the columns are:

```
+---+-------------------------------+
|ID | link  | image       | active  |
+---+-------+-------------+---------+
|1  |#link1 | image1      | 0       |
|2  |#link2 | image2      | 1       |
|3  |#link3 | image3      | 0       |
+---+-------+-------------+---------+
```

there you can see row #2 is active. how can i update next row based on latest active row? also if active row is the last row, then set first row as active row.

PS: I will do the query using cron, update every 2 hours for example. no problem about the cron, I did it.

Comment: How many rows can be active at a specific moment?

Comment: do you have an autoincrement column in your table?

Comment: having auto increment  column will resolve this issue

Comment: ah yes sorry, my mistake. there is auto increment column. question updated

Comment: What would the data set look like AFTER the query?

Comment: Folks, after an update, ID=3 will be active. After another update, ID=1 will be active. Then again ID=2...

Comment: You don't really need to store this.

Answer (score 0):

use this stored procedure :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE updateActiveRow()
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(ID) INTO @activeID FROM banners WHERE active;
    UPDATE banners SET active=1 WHERE ID > @activeID LIMIT 1;
    IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
        UPDATE banners SET active=1 ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1;
    END IF;
    UPDATE banners SET active=0 WHERE ID = @activeID;/*do this only if you want to deactivate current active row*/
END //
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,
I solved it myself. here is the code

```
class Job{
    private $con;
    function __construct(){
        $this->con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'egoji');
    }

    function getCurrentActiveID(){
        $q = "SELECT id FROM banners WHERE active='1'";
        $result = $this->con->query($q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['id'];
    }

    function getNextID($id){
        $q = "SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM banners WHERE id > '{$id}'";
        $result = $this->con->query($q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        return $row['id'];
    }

    function isLastRow(){
        $currentActiveId = $this->getCurrentActiveID();

        $q = "SELECT id FROM banners ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $result = $this->con->query($q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        return $row['id'] == $currentActiveId ? true:false;
    }

    function updateFirstRow(){
        $q = "SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM banners";
        $result = $this->con->query($q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $this->deactivateAll();

        $update_q = "UPDATE banners SET active='1' WHERE id='{$row['id']}'";
        $this->con->query($update_q);
    }

    function updateNextRow(){

        $currentActiveId = $this->getCurrentActiveID();
        $nextID = $this->getNextID($currentActiveId);

        $this->deactivateAll();

        $update_q = "UPDATE banners SET active='1' WHERE id='{$nextID}'";
        $this->con->query($update_q);
    }

    function deactivateAll(){
        $update_q = "UPDATE banners SET active='0'";
        $this->con->query($update_q);
    }

    function doit(){
        if($this->isLastRow()){
            $this->updateFirstRow();
        }else{
            $this->updateNextRow();
        }
    }
}

$job = new Job;
$job->doit();
```

I am open to any suggestions or correction.

Answer (score 0):

[Tested SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a2c6/1)

```
SET @activeID = (SELECT ID FROM Banners WHERE active = 1);
SET @isLast = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Banners) LIKE @activeID;

UPDATE Banners
SET active = IF(ID = @activeID, 0, IF(ID = @activeID+1, 1, active));

UPDATE Banners
SET active = IF(@isLast AND ID = 1, 1, active);
```